# SQL Server 2005: Sharing processors accross multiple distributed instances

Tags: sql-server, central-processing-unit, distribution

I have two instances of SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition running on two separate dedicated servers (let's call them DB1 and DB2). At the moment DB1 is very busy and DB2 is mostly idle. Is it possible to configure the instance running on DB1 to utilize the processor on DB2?

For example, I connect to DB1 and execute "sp-heavy-going" and I would like DB1 to process this request using DB2's processor. Whats the best way to go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  The long answer is, yes, sort of.  If you spend a ton of time making sure that your database and application are setup to handle this.

If you were to host the same database on both servers, and use SQL Replication to ensure that the databases are synced between them, then you could put a load balancer in front of the SQL Servers and have clients connect to the load balancer instead of a single SQL Server.  However this creates it's own set of issues that have to be addressed first.

A better option might be to look at federating your database so that half the data is stored on each server and data is queried from the server which holds that data.  However this is also an extremely tough thing to get setup correctly.

Has the database been properly tuned so that the indexes are all created in the best possible setup?

Comment: thanks mrdenny. we will consider some of these options. our servers have a lot of usage and the thing that takes up most resource is full text search. we are trying to squeeze some new functionality into our app and our servers just can't take it. as far as I know we have tuned our databases to the best of our ability.

I think what we will do is to replicate the databases and run the new features against the replicated readonly database.

Comment: If full text search is taking the bulk of the power, then you should consider an upgrade to SQL 2008.  Full text search was completely rewritten and is much more efficient in SQL 2008 then it was before.